# Circular module dependency in python

Tags: python, circular-dependency, python-module

I have two modules, baselib.Database and baselib.Application. 
In baselib.Application, I have

```
import baselib.Database

APP = None
class BaseApplication():
    def __init__(dbClass = baselib.Database.GenericDb...):
        global APP
        this.dbClass = dbClass
        APP = this
        etc...
```

In baselib.Database, I have

```
import baselib.Application

def getDB(dbClass = baselib.Application.APP.dbClass):
    etc...

class GenericDB():
    def __init__(self, args):
    etc...
```

The problem is, when I import either of these modules, I get

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute (modulename)
```

The problem seems to stem from the fact that the default arguments are evaluated during the import; if I replace getDB with

```
def getDB(dbClass = None):
    dbClass = dbClass or baselib.Application.APP.dbClass
```

and do the same thing with the other default argument, everything works fine. Is this the best/most pythonic way to do this, or should I just avoid the circular dependency entirely and combine the two modules into one file? I'd really like to keep them separate because a large part of my codebase is dependent on them.

Comment: That error isn't because of any code that you've posted. Please post your full code along with the full stack trace of your error.

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the declaration of the GenericDB class in baselib.Database.

Comment: That still doesn't help. Please post your full code.

Comment: The full code is a declaration of the BaseApplication and GenericDB classes, which are several hundred lines of irrelevant code of a class that's not even instantiated anywhere in either module. Since changing the lines posted above fixes my error, I'm sure it's in there somewhere.

Comment: No, you aren't sure. If you were sure, you wouldn't have made this post. By asking for help you are acknowledging that the greater Stack Overflow community collectively knows more than you do. Code that you deem irrelevant could very well be the issue.

Comment: I am sure. My question wasn't how to fix the problem (as I mentioned above, I'd already gotten a solution for it), it was if this was the best way to do it. I've commented the rest of both the files (besides the snippets above) and tried importing them, and gotten the same error. When I make the changes mentioned above, the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports may answer your question. Basically, import is also a statement. We should avoid circular module dependency.

Comment: So my only other option is to combine the two modules into one?

Comment: @sfendell I think, in any languages, circular dependency is bad. And in python if you want to use other object, you don't have to import the definition, the binding happens in run time.